# numpyで特定のaxisの値に応じて処理を変えたい

Tags: python, numpy

pythonのnumpyを使って、特定のaxisの値に応じて処理を変えたいと思っています。

例えば、下記のような `a[3][3][3]` のndarrayがあった際に

```
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]]

 [[ 9 10 11]
  [12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]]

 [[18 19 20]
  [21 22 23]
  [24 25 26]]]
```

`a[:, :, :1]` に対しては10以上を0に上書きし、`a[:, :, 1:2]` に対しては15以上を0に上書きし、`a[:, :, 2:]` に対しては20以上を0に上書きする処理をしたいと思っています。

numpyの関数を調べて、下記の手順で実装して意図通りの処理ができるようになりましたが、スライスを用いている個所を、(スライスを用いない)スマートな処理ができないかを考えております。

1. スライスを用いてndarrayを分割する
2. それぞれのndarrayに対して処理を実施する
3. 再度dstackでndarrayをまとめる。

おそらく何か適切な関数があると考えているのですが、そのような処理に適切か関数はありますでしょうか？

```
import numpy as np

def main():
    a = np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3)
    print(a)

    a0 = a[:, :, :1]
    a1 = a[:, :, 1:2]
    a2 = a[:, :, 2:]

    a0_update = np.where(a0 < 10, a0, 0)
    a1_update = np.where(a1 < 15, a1, 0)
    a2_update = np.where(a2 < 20, a2, 0)

    a_update = np.dstack((a0_update, a1_update, a2_update))

    print(a_update.shape)
    print(a_update)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[numpy.moveaxis — NumPy v1.23 Manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html)

> **Returns:　result :** ***np.ndarray***
>
> Array with moved axes. This array is **a view** of the input array.

```py
b = np.moveaxis(a, -1, 0)
for i, n in enumerate([10, 15, 20]):
    b[i][b[i] >= n] = 0

print(a)

#
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]]

 [[ 9 10 11]
  [ 0 13 14]
  [ 0  0 17]]

 [[ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

ブールインデックスを使って以下のようにすればできますよ

```
a[a >= np.array([10, 15, 20])] = 0
```

Comment: お見事！(以降は「コメントは8文字以上」ということなので入力しています。なので無視して下さい)

Answer (score 1):

> (スライスを用いない)スマートな処理ができないか

スマートかどうかは見る人によって変わるかもだけど

```py
for n in range(3):
    a[a[..., n] >= [10,15,20][n], n] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.moveaxis()` を使う回答の焼き直しですが，転置を使ってみました。

ただし， `moveaxis(a, -1, 0)` は（軸2, 軸0, 軸1）へ，転置は（軸2, 軸1, 軸0）へと軸を移動するので，両者の配列 `b` は（今回は影響しないですが）異なります。

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3)

b = a.T.copy()
b[0][b[0] >= 10] = 0
b[1][b[1] >= 15] = 0
b[2][b[2] >= 20] = 0

a_update = b.T
print(a_update)
```

ちなみに，個人的には下記も嫌いじゃないです。

```
a_update = a.copy()

a_update[..., 0][a_update[..., 0] >= 10] = 0
a_update[..., 1][a_update[..., 1] >= 15] = 0
a_update[..., 2][a_update[..., 2] >= 20] = 0

print(a_update)
```